# Appending the list with nested lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list which will be like

```
list = [[0, 35], [1,56], [2,65],[3,40],[9,54] ......[99999,56]]
```

The list structure is nested lists with 1st element is always an integer from 0 to 99999, and second element is some random value.

Now, the question is : i want to append the list with the missing first element integers ex: in above list 4, 5, ..8 and many more are missing. 
And with the appended list, i want second element as the maximum number of second elements.
The output should be like

```
list = [[0, 35], [1,56], [2,65],[3,40],[4,x], [5,x] ......[99999,56]]
```

where x is maximum of [35,56,65,.....56].

Thanks for the enquiring about my code, please consider the following my code

```
def CompleteList (raw_list):
raw_list.sort()
#print len(raw_list)

sequence_num_list = [item[0] for item in my_list]
rtt_list          = [item[1] for item in my_list]
rtt_max           = max(rtt_list)
#print rtt_max
#print len(sequence_num_list)
packet_lost_list  = list(sorted(set(range(0, 100000)) - set(sequence_num_list)))
print ('Packet Lost =%i' %len(packet_lost_list))

packet_lost_with_max_RTT = []
for i in range(len(packet_lost_list)):
    packet_lost_with_max_RTT.append([packet_lost_list[i],rtt_max])

#print len(packet_lost_with_max_RTT)

new_list = raw_list + packet_lost_with_max_RTT
print ('Length of new list =%i' %len(new_list))
return new_list
```

rtt_list represents second elements.
packet_lost_list represent compliment list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
list_ = [[0, 35], [1,56], [2,65],[3,40],[9,54] ......[99999,56]]
max_sec_elem = max(i[1] for i in list_)
missing_first_elem = set(range(100000)) ^ set(i[0] for i in list_)
for i in missing_first_elem:
    list_.append([i, max_sec_elem])
```